# How do I add only certain columns to a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor, addition

Consider the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

test=tf.constant([[[100., 2., -30.],[-4,5,6]], [[4., 5., 6.],[-7,8,9]]]) # matrix

print(test)

test1=tf.constant([[[100.]],[[  8.]]])

print(test1)
```

When adding test1 to the first two columns of test we would get the following output:

```
print(test[:,:,0:2]+test1)
```

I do not want to add test1 variable to the last column of the test variable, but at the same time I would like to include the last column of the test variable in the output unchanged:

```
[[[200. 102., -30.]
  [ 96. 105., 6.]]

 [[ 12.  13., 6]
  [  1.  16., 9]]]
```

How would I code this quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option would be to just use `tf.concat`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

test = tf.constant([[[100., 2., -30.],[-4,5,6]], [[4., 5., 6.],[-7,8,9]]]) # matrix
test1 = tf.constant([[[100.]],[[  8.]]])

print(tf.concat([test[:,:,0:2] + test1, test[:,:,2:]], axis=-1))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[200. 102. -30.]
  [ 96. 105.   6.]]

 [[ 12.  13.   6.]
  [  1.  16.   9.]]], shape=(2, 2, 3), dtype=float32)
```